# How to run portion of code in lower execution level

Tags: c#

I develop a Console App in C# which needs to run as administrator (required by some calls to sqllocaldb.exe and sqlcmd.exe), so my app.manifest has this line :

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

At some point I create a directory with

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("mypath");
```

Then copy some .mdf file that I later use in SqlCmd to create a database.
My problem is that as the directory is created as administrator the file I copy is restricted in write access and thus provoke an exception in sqlserver : 
    **Database [Database_Name] cannot be upgraded because it is read-only or has read-only files**

Is it possible to run the portion of code that do the directory creation / file copying as a simple user ?
OR
Can I specifically create my directory with no protected access ?

**NOTE : I've looked in the DirectorySecurity / FileSecurity stuff, but the FileSystemAccessRule constructor needs to be passed the account name as a string, problem : I don't know the account name / group name of my user. So I could use "Everyone", but what if my user's system is set to French (as I am) or German ?**

Comment: If the program is running as admin it should be possible to set whatever rights you want to the directory.

Comment: The right keyword for your search should be "elevated privileges" or "self elevate". A search would bring for example this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981778

Comment: @Magnus : Actually, I can with dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType));
But I can't know in advance what will be the user account, neither his culture (for the Everyone account)

Comment: @user743414 : You may have misread my question, I'm already running as administrator

Comment: Mh, that's my bad. :) But when running as an admin already, why you don't simply change the access rights on the copied file? That should solve your problem or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the "Everyone" right like this without knowing the culture.

```
var sec = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
var everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, sec);
```